# Ruby - Appending data in a new line without introducing an empty line

Tags: ruby

I already have one line in `fd.txt` and when I'm inserting three multiple lines, the first line appends right after the existing data. Here's an example:

**fd.txt**

```
This is past data.
```

**New data**

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

When I run the following code:

```rb
open('fd.txt', 'a+') { |file|
  file.puts "Line 1"
  file.puts "Line 2"
  file.puts "Line 3"
}
```

I get the following output:

```
This is past data.Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

But, I need `Line 1` from the second line. So I add `"\n"` in `file.puts "\nLine 1"` but this adds an additional empty line right before `Line 1`. What update should I make to my code to get the following output:

```
This is past data.
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Comment: *but this adds an additional empty line right before Line 1* -- No, it doesn't. At a guess, my prediction for what's happened here is you re-saved the `fd.txt`, and your text editor is configured to append a new line to the end of the file, if none is present. It is often considered standard practice to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the other proposed answer, you could do:

```
open('fd.txt', 'a+') do |file|
  file.seek(-1, IO::SEEK_END)
  file.puts unless file.read == "\n"

  file.puts "Line 1"
  file.puts "Line 2"
  file.puts "Line 3"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Not very elegant, but you could check whether the last character is a `\n` and add one otherwise: (I assume that you don't *know* if the file ends with a newline)

```
open('fd.txt', 'a+') do |file|
  file.puts unless file.pread(1, file.size - 1) == "\n"

  file.puts "Line 1"
  file.puts "Line 2"
  file.puts "Line 3"
end
```

It would be better of course to not have a missing newline in the first place.

Comment: Too bad `IO#pread` doesn't permit `file.pread(1, -1) == "\n"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland that was the first I’ve tried!